# XamlServices.Load exception message truncated when running in nunit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xaml, nunit

here's my problem.

I have the following unit test:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldParseXaml()
{
    try
    {
        XamlServices.Load("Filel.xaml");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Assert.Fail(e.Message);
    }
}
```

When this unit test is run automatically via a GUI test runner, I get the following exception message:

```
Add value to dictionary of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(System.UInt32,
System.Collections.Generic.List(MyXamlFramework.IConfigurationFieldNameProvider))'
threw an exception.
    at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message, Object[] args)
    at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message)
    at XamlBehaviour.ShouldParseXaml3() in C:\test\XamlBehaviour.cs:line 62#0
```

If however, I place a breakpoint on the Assert.Fail(e.Message) and then continue to let the test run after it breaks, I get following exception message:

```
'Add value to dictionary of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(System.UInt32,
System.Collections.Generic.List(MyXamlFramework.IConfigurationFieldNameProvider))'
threw an exception.' Line number '70' and line position '11'.
    at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message, Object[] args)
    at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Fail(String message)
    at XamlBehaviour.ShouldParseXaml3() in C:\test\XamlBehaviour.cs:line 62#0
```

If possible, I'd really like to retain the full exception message which includes the line and position number when the test is auto run.

Thanks for your help.